# Using series for determining the convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

We apply the integral test for determining the convergence of series . For example integral test is useful for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}$ . Because the integral test is biconditional , I thought about the other way . I mean determining the convergence of the improper integral with the help of series . Is it practical ? What are the examples for it ?

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks but we can easily solve that integral without help of series . I'm interested in cases in which solving integral by itself is not possible and then we use series .

Comment: it can be used sometimes, however it is not so practical. The reasons is that there are more tools to use to calculate integrals than tools to calculate series. Moreover: the comparison just works in the case of non-negative integrands, but there are convergent improper integrals that are not absolutely convergent

Comment: @Masacroso Yes , I agree with you . It was just interesting to think about that .

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In some cases, it is practical. Consider, for instance, the integral $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty\frac1{x(x-1)}\,\mathrm dx$. Then\begin{align}\int_2^\infty\frac1{x(x-1)}\,\mathrm dx\text{ converges}&\iff\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\text{ converges}\\&\iff\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\text{ converges,}\end{align}and it is clear that the last statment holds (it's a telescoping series).

Comment: Thanks , it was interesting example . Do you know a case in which solving integral by itself is not possible and then we use series for determining convergence of integral ?

Comment: Right now, I can't think of an example.

Comment: Okay , thanks again .